# How to format the DOI field in BibTeX?

Tags: biblatex, urls, doi

I would like to format the word `doi` to be `\textsc{DOI}` **as it is for the `url` field**.

How to achieve this?

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@dataset{Thomas2021,
    doi = {10.17632/wj6s2d8xbg.2},
    year = {2021},
    publisher = {Mendeley Data},
    author = {S. Thomas},
    title = {Finite Periodic Topology Optimization with Oriented Unit-cells Data Set},
    note = {V2},
    url = {https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/wj6s2d8xbg/2},
    urldate = {2022-02-16},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \textsc{DOI}\addcolon\space   % <--- This doesn't work
    \ifhyperref
        {\href{http://doi.org/\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#1}}}
        \space
}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}   % Even non-cited BibTeX entries will be shown
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use lower case to get small caps: `\textsc{doi}`

Comment: Note that the `\space` as `<false>` branch of the `\ifhyperref` test looks very fishy. If you don't load `hyperref`, you get only a space instead of the DOI. The original definition can be found in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/64156e27b9501bab86cab5ed9ee58e8a6a5ce67f/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def#L500-L504 and has `{\nolinkurl{#1}}` instead of `\space`. The standard definition's `\mkbibacro{DOI}` already gives you DOI in small caps if small caps are available. So in theory you could probably delete the whole field redefinition and get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lower case to get small caps:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@dataset{Thomas2021,
    doi = {10.17632/wj6s2d8xbg.2},
    year = {2021},
    publisher = {Mendeley Data},
    author = {S. Thomas},
    title = {Finite Periodic Topology Optimization with Oriented Unit-cells Data Set},
    note = {V2},
    url = {https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/wj6s2d8xbg/2},
    urldate = {2022-02-16},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{%
    \textsc{doi}\addcolon\space   % <--- doi instead of DOI
    \ifhyperref
        {\href{http://doi.org/\detokenize{#1}}{\detokenize{#1}}}
        \space
}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\nocite{*}   % Even non-cited BibTeX entries will be shown
\printbibliography[title={Bibliography}]

\end{document}
```

[image]